# Save multiple rows on multilevel associated tables - Cake PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have got stuck on Multilevel associated tables in Cake PHP code.

I have the following models

Guardian who has many students and the various students have their studentfees. When I create a guardian with 2 students, an associated 2 row must be created for StudentFees table. Im successful in adding 2 students when adding a guardian, but I dont know how to add the 2 rows of fees for the student. My code is as below.

```
    class Guardian extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Guardian';

    public $recursive =2;
    public $hasMany = array(
            'Student' => array(
                'className'     => 'Student',
                'dependent'     => true
            )
    );

}
class Student extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Student';

        public $hasMany = array(
            'StudentFee' => array(
                'className'     => 'StudentFee',
                'dependent'     => true
            )
    );
}
class StudentFee extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'StudentFee';
    public $belongsTo = array(
                    'Student' => array(
                    'className'     => 'Student',
                    'dependent'     => true
            )
    );
}
```

Pl help me to save the studenFee details too. I use SaveAssociated function that saves guardian and Student details.

Comment: Please try `$Student->saveAssociated($data, array('deep' => true));` Please refer http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-hasone-hasmany-belongsto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this should do the trick:

`Model::saveAll()` should take care of it for you and select the appropriate method, `saveMany` or `saveAssociated`. Moreover, it will automatically set your foreignKeys so everything is neatly inserted into the database.

```
$this->Guardian->saveAll(array('Guardian' => array(
   [...],
   'Student' => array(
       0 => array(
          [here's your first Student],
          'StudentFee'  => array(
             0 => array(
                [here's your first StudentFee]
             )
          )
       )
    )
)));
```

Answer (score 0):

can use `saveAll` and `saveAssociated` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this method, which i always use in such situations :

```
$this->Studentfee->create();

$this->Studentfee->set(array(
'field1' => 'value',
'field2' => 'value'
));

 $this->Studentfee->save();
```

and you can put in a loop for all student fees